# An ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique occurred in registrations#create WHY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, unicorn, rails-activerecord

I get an exception and I want to understand why. I've created a git repo so anyone can test it.

The rails app is fresh with Devise installed on it.

Running the app and this script that try to create the same user:

```
1000.times do
  fork do
    `curl -d "user[email]=your@mail.com&user[password]=pwd&user[password_confirmation]=pwd" localhost:3000/users`
  end
end
```

I get the follow exception:

```
An ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique occurred in registrations#create:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'your@mail.com' for key 'index_users_on_email': INSERT INTO `users` (`authentication_token`, `confirmation_sent_at`, `confirmation_token`, `confirmed_at`, `created_at`, `current_sign_in_at`, `current_sign_in_ip`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `failed_attempts`, `last_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_ip`, `locked_at`, `remember_created_at`, `reset_password_sent_at`, `reset_password_token`, `sign_in_count`, `unconfirmed_email`, `unlock_token`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '2013-01-24 16:48:23', 'GQwbJzsawxRsbvhp1LkR', NULL, '2013-01-24 16:48:23', NULL, NULL, 'your@mail.com', '$2a$10$koMNiiZQuhkeWhmYV8PtcOUlvi6rZHTKMs82MGWNa2M/GsUQ0cIHO', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, '2013-01-24 16:48:23')
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
```

Why I get this exception and not a validation error? If I try to create an user with an email that is already used from the web page "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up" I dont get this exception but a validation error...

If I run the script without fork (request are sequential), I get no error.

Seems a race conditions problem.

Comment: User email must be unique. https://github.com/pioz/test_duplicate_entry/blob/master/db/schema.rb#L41

Comment: git repo https://github.com/pioz/test_duplicate_entry

Comment: The validations are included by Devise gem.

Comment: Ok, found this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of-label-Concurrency+and+integrity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script you try to create 1000 users all with the email "your@mail.com". You have a uniqueness constraint on your user email index (correctly - you only want one user per email address). The second time it tries to create a user with that email you will get the error.

As you are forking your request the `validates_uniqueness_of` validation provided by devise may be succeeding because it queries for another record with the same email. But, by the time the record is actually written, another record may exist.

For example,

1. Request 1 checks for existing email "your@mail.com" - okay
2. Request 2 checks for existing email "your@mail.com" - okay
3. Request 1 writes record with email "your@mail.com" - okay
4. Request 2 writes record with email "your@mail.com" - uniqueness violation.

Comment: Ok, so can I avoid this exception?

Comment: Not really and I'd question if it really matters. What is the likelihood in production of two users registering simultaneously with the same email address? Do you want to spend a lot of time coding for that unlikely event? If it does happen then you get a decent enough error message and, most importantly, you still have unique email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's like the exception says, you're violating the index uniqueness constraint. When you run the Devise generators, it creates a migration for you (it's the only one you have in db/migrate in your test app). In this migration you have this:

```
add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
```

This is what makes your script fail when you try to create a thousand record with the same email.

For starters, I'd change your sample script to something like this, so you get a unique mail each time:

```
1000.times do |i|
  fork do
    `curl -d "user[email]=your#{i}@mail.com&user[password]=pwd&user[password_confirmation]=pwd" localhost:3000/users`
  end
end
```

If what you're trying to do is seed the development database with fake users, check out railscasts on [database population](http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database) and [seed data](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data).

Comment: I'm trying to create the same user, but why is there that exception instead of a validation error?

Comment: Simple: because you don't have any such validation in your model. You should have a `validates :email, uniqueness: true` in `user.rb` for this to work. What I fail to understand is why you're trying to create the same user a 1000 times???

Comment: If I try to create an user with an email that is already used from the web page "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up" I dont get this exception but a validation error... The validation of the email field is in Devise gem.

Comment: OK I've overlooked the `:validatable` part in your user model. First thing I can think of is you're actually running into a race condition between your requests. What happens if you take out the `fork` and run the requests sequentially?

Comment: OK so this is your answer. Maybe if you can specifically explain why you're trying to do this, I can give you a more specific one.

Comment: Because in a my project in production I get this exception and I want to try to avoid this exception. How can I avoid this exception?

Answer (score -2):

Devise uses the email as the unique identifier of your User. You can't assign the same email to all of them.

Or maybe what you tried to do in your script is to update the user instead of creating new ones?

Comment: No, I'm trying to create the same user, but why is there that exception instead of a validation error?

Comment: Coming late to the party, you get an exception because a raise condition is happening not a validation error: `create!` would raise a validation error, what you are experienced is a race condition within `first_or_create`